# Test Sounds Missing After Messing With Pulseaudio and JACK

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, preferences

So after installing JACK and using 'sudo usermod -a -G audio username' and restarted. This made JACK work however no program using pulseaudio (more or less everything) made any sound. I purge removed Pulseaudio, restarted, reinstalled it, restarted and finally the sound was working again. The only place sound won't come from is the test area in sound preferences.

I realise that performing a command I know little about was daft and that those test sounds aren't of very high importance, but I like things to run as intended. If anyone can help, it'd be very appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?  I think there were problems with the alert sounds in 11.10 while running Compiz.  Also, there is a volume control that only affects alerts somewhere in the sound settings, so make sure it's not muted or set to minimum.

Comment: I'm running the 12.10 Beta, upgraded from 12.04. I've made sure that isn't muted.

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of ideas.  I am running 11.10, and somehow seem to have fixed it, but I don't remember doing so.  I do remember it didn't work at one point, but I don't know if it got fixed or if I fixed it somehow.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

When you uninstalled pulseaudio, other programs and libraries were removed as dependencies.
To find out what they are (so you can reinstall them) look at the log.

The log is located here:
`/var/log/dpkg.log`

Look for the line that contains "remove pulseaudio" (without the quotes)
Above that line you will see what was removed as a dependency, here's what I found:

```
projectm-data
paprefs
libftgl2
libprojectm2
libprojectm-qt1
projectm-pulseaudio
libcanberra-pulse
indicator-sound
```

You can install these items with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install projectm-data paprefs libftgl2 libprojectm2 libprojectm-qt1 projectm-pulseaudio libcanberra-pulse indicator-sound
```

The one causing your particular issue is `libcanberra-pulse`

`indicator-sound` is the one that shows a volume icon at the top in Unity